# Using Python help throws SEGFAULT

Tags: python, segmentation-fault

While using Python help I typed modules and got the following error:

```
help>   modules

Please wait a moment while I gather a list of all available modules...

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gobject/constants.py:24: Warning: g_boxed_type_register_static: assertion `g_type_from_name (name) == 0' failed
  import gobject._gobject
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: g_boxed_type_register_static: assertion `g_type_from_name (name) == 0' failed
  from gtk import _gtk

** (python:12351): CRITICAL **: pyg_register_boxed: assertion `boxed_type != 0' failed
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: cannot register existing type `GdkDevice'
  from gtk import _gtk
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: g_type_get_qdata: assertion `node != NULL' failed
  from gtk import _gtk
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

See also: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7/+bug/896836

How can I fix or get around this issue and get the help I want?

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Seems kinda obvious when getting an error, but ok, added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such "lists of modules" (`pydoc -k` too) require importing everything available into one process and this may cause all kinds of problems. Don't do that.

See also http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=697402