# Python 2.7 on Linux crashes on the help('modules') command

Tags: python, ubuntu

When running the python interpreter on ubuntu 12.04 LTS and entering the command >>help('modules') it crashes and I can't determine the module that is causing the crash.  I think I have added about three modules some of them being python-twitter, feedparser for now but I am not able to get an inventory of what on there now. Also some of my code runs regularly as well.

Here is what the crash looks like...

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gobject/constants.py:24: Warning: g_boxed_type_register_static: assertion `g_type_from_name (name) == 0' failed
  import gobject._gobject
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: g_boxed_type_register_static: assertion `g_type_from_name (name) == 0' failed
  from gtk import _gtk

** (python:23199): CRITICAL **: pyg_register_boxed: assertion `boxed_type != 0' failed
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: cannot register existing type `GdkDevice'
  from gtk import _gtk
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: g_type_get_qdata: assertion `node != NULL' failed
  from gtk import _gtk
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
root@m:~/Settings# python -V
Python 2.7.3
```

Comment: As per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557658/import-errors-with-python-and-gtk-3?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14812520/using-python-help-throws-segfault?rq=1, I think the problem arises because you're importing some incompatible modules (maybe two interfaces to GTK), which can't be used simultaneously. The solution is just ["don't do that"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14812973/344643).